# How to determine the value for the gate resistor (Rg) of a MOSFET in low side configuration?

Tags: mosfet, comparator, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, fsr

Once the FSR is pressed the output of the comparator should go high. This, will drive the MOSFET ON which has a DC motor on its drain terminal. I was wondering how can I determine the value in ohms of the gate resistor? should it use one at all? Thanks.

Comparators' data sheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCS2250-D.PDF

[image]

Comment: For this application it's entirely non-critical.  If I were building this ckt I'd use 1kΩ and call it a day -- it's plenty to isolate the op-amp output from any "ringing" from the input capacitance (however for this app, honestly you really wouldn't care too much even if you HAD ringing) and also small enough not to add too much delay (you're only turning on a motor).  The input capacitance of a typical mosfet ~ 1000pF which is small.  If you had a 100Ω or even a 10kΩ both would work fine too.  Very, very, noncritical.  In fact, you could eliminate it entirely "in theory"...

Answer (score 1):

In general the comparator has to supply the gate charge to turn the MOSFET on and off. With a gate charge in the 100nC range, 1mA will allow switching within 1ms or so.

You can compare the 400mA maximum load current and the switching time to the SOA (Safe Operating Area) of the MOSFET you have in mind. The worst-case stress on the transistor is when it is turning on (or prematurely off) with a few hundred mA flowing and most of the supply voltage across the MOSFET.

And, BTW, don't depend on Vgs(th), depend on the guaranteed Rds(on) with your minimum supply voltage. For example, [this](http://www.vishay.com/docs/69653/si4448dy.pdf) one (SI4448) which is guaranteed to have an Rds(on) of less than 2.5m\$\Omega\$ with drive >= 2.5V.

The comparator specs are guaranteed with 4mA output and capable of about 50mA drive, so you could arbitrarily pick a resistor in the 100 ohm to 1K range. If you check the the SOA on the SI4448, you'll see that it's not limiting for your situation.

You *need* a diode across the motor to deal with the motor inductance, or else you'll  probably avalanche the MOSFET with the voltage spike when the MOSFET switches off.

Probably not an issue in your case, but also note that if the motor was externally driven in reverse it will produce voltage which could cause issues.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I'm not familiar with Rds nomenclature. Does Rds reffer to the resistance/impedance of the transistors output?. In class I have seen that every transistor has an Rout that is used to test sources which is equal to Ro=Vo/Io. Is that the same? thanks.

Comment: Rds(on) is Resistance from Drain to Source with a certain Vgs (Voltage from Gate to Source). It's a specification in every MOSFET datasheet, including the one I linked above (virtually the first thing on the datasheet, which indicates how important it is to designers).